# How to create a graph with data from a text file with Python

Tags: python, graph

So after retrieving important information from a text document I would like to create a graph plotting the data below. I would like to have the time on the x-axis and the other data on the y-axis.

As I am a beginner I found few leads that led me to use panda and numpy but I don't understand everything.

The text file is formatted as follows:

```
  NAV TIME    RPE - NMILES

   --------    -------- 

    5  min      0.011530

    10 min      0.039914

    15 min      0.085069

    20 min      0.145798

    25 min      0.213572

    30 min      0.287898

    35 min      0.355587

    40 min      0.413209

    45 min      0.472346
```

the code that allowed me to get what I wanted :

```
def mfileopen():
  i = 0 
  ln = 396

  fileTXT = open(filedialog.askopenfilename(),"r")
  content = fileTXT.readlines()

  FILE=open("NAV.txt",'w')
  
  while i < 33:

    FILE.write(content[ln])
    FILE.write("\n") 

    if ln == 427 :
      ln=0

  ln= ln+ 1
  i = i + 1
  
  return 0
```

Comment: `I don't understand everything` ... what do you not understand?

Comment: @jsotola i would like to know how i can transform the data i get into a graph

Comment: If you are using pandas, you only need two functions: `pandas.read_csv()` (setting `sep=' '`) and `pandas.DataFrame.plot()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried to turn my text into two different lists and this is what happens :

The code :

```
  l1=[]
  l2=[]
  read_file=open('NAV.txt','r')
  split= [line.strip() for line in read_file]
  for line in split:
      l1.append(line.split('  ')[0].strip())
      l2.append('  '.join(line.split('  ')[1:]).strip())
  print (l1,l2)
```

Output :

```
['5', '10 min', '15 min', '20 min', '25 min', '30 min', '35 min', '40 min', '45 min', ''] ['min      0.011530', '0.039914', '0.085069', '0.145798', '0.213572', '0.287898', '0.355587', '0.413209', '0.472346', '']
```

So i am having some issues, how can I delete the "min" and keep the numbers ?

Comment: I will try to delete "min" before making the list

Answer (score 0):

OK so i deleted the "min" before making any lists heres the code :

```
def deletemin():
  f = open("NAV.txt",'rt')
  inputfilecontents = f.read()
  newline = re.sub("min","",inputfilecontents)
  f = open("NAVClean.txt","w")
  f.write(newline)
```

after that i use this to make my two different list :

```
def Filetolist():
  l1=[]
  l2=[]
  read_file=open('NAVClean.txt','r')
  split= [line.strip() for line in read_file]
  for line in split:
      l1.append(line.split('  ')[0].strip())
      l2.append('  '.join(line.split('  ')[1:]).strip())
  print(l1,l2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(
    [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
    [0.011530, 0.039914, 0.085069, 0.145798,
     0.213572, 0.287898, 0.355587, 0.413209, 0.472346]
)

plt.show()
```

Comment: how I can do this in a more automated way ?

Comment: Read your file into two lists like you see in this answer, instead of the constant-value lists used in this example.